# create table in postgresql fails - tablespace issue

Tags: http-post

I am trying to create a the following table in postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE retail_demo.categories_dim_hawq
(
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    category_name character varying(400) NOT NULL
)
WITH (appendonly=true, compresstype=quicklz) DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR:  cannot get table space location for content 0 table space 1663
>   (catalog.c:97)

I tried to create a new tablespace, I got the following:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOCATION" LINE 1: create TABLESPACE
>   moha LOCATION "/tmp/abc";

Thanks in advance,
Moha.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
you’ll need to create a filespace, tablespace, database, and then create the table to do this follow the following steps:
12. If you are on the default database (using plsql command), you can get out to root db user (gpadmin) using CTRL + D.
13. gpfilespace -o .
14. enter the name of the filespace: hawqfilespace3
15. Choose filesystem name for this filespace: hdfs
16. Enter replica num for filespace: 0
17. Specify the HDFS location for the segments: bigdata01.intrasoft.com.jo:8020/xd
Note that /xd is one of Hadoop directories which has read write access.
18. The system will generate a configuration command to you, just execute it.
19. Copy and paste the command and click on enter to execute it.
20. The file space is now created successfully.
21. Now connect to the Database using the psql command.
22. Now create a tablespace on the file space you created.
create TABLESPACE hawqtablespace3 FILESPACE hawqfilespace3;
23. Create a database on this tablespace using the command.
CREATE DATABASE hawqdatabase3 WITH OWNER gpadmin TEMPLATE=template0 TABLESPACE hawqtablespace3; 
24. Now you need to connect to the database you created, but first click CTRL + D to exit the user you are in.
25. Enter the command psql hawqdatabase3